# Is it possible to show a remote connected console?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, remote-control, winexe

I'm connected from a Linux machine to a Windows machine through winexe. I log onto the Windows machine with a user on that machine. 
I can run cmd.exe or powershell scripts.

Now my problem: If I'm on the desktop of the machine, connect remotly to it and start some script through cmd/powershell then the cmd/powershell window is not visible to the desktop user. Both use the same user. I would like to have a visible window for the desktop user if a remote user started a script and it is running, so the commands and the output can be seen by the desktop user.

If I use the interactive argument of winexe then I get a message on the desktop that an interactive serivce needs attention, but when I look at it then there is only an empty cmd window. The output doesn't show.

Is there a way to show the cmd window that is used by the remote user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try executing your script using `psexec` and specifying the interactive session switch. Something like:

```
psexec.exe -i powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file C:\myscript.ps1
```

[psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)